# Table does not exist error

Tags: php, mysql, sql, create-table

```
$sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS questions_$username(".
        "question_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, ".
        "question MEDIUMTEXT, ".
        "answer CHAR(1), ".
        "PRIMARY KEY (question_id))";
$retval = mysql_query($sql, $conn) or die(mysql_error());

$sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tests_$username(".
        "test_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, ".
        "name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL, ".
        "duration INT NOT NULL, ".
        "PRIMARY KEY (test_id))";
$retval = mysql_query($sql, $conn) or die(mysql_error());

$sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS questions_tests_$username(".
        "test_id INT NOT NULL, ".
        "question_id INT NOT NULL, ".
        "FOREIGN KEY (test_id) REFERENCES tests_$username(test_id), ".
        "FOREIGN KEY (question_id) REFERENCES questions_$username(question_id), ".
        "PRIMARY KEY (test_id, question_id))".
$retval = mysql_query($sql, $conn) or die(mysql_error());

echo "debug";
```

The first 2 tables are created successfully, but the third one doesn't. It doesn't even give any error. The last line gets executed. There is no limit on number of tables in my database.

Comment: [**Please please _please_, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: Also, Please please please, don't create new tables for each user in your system. That's an antipattern that will kill your application, your server, yourself, your family, and everyone whose name begins with an 'S'

Comment: Could you try adding an echo $sql after each statement to see what string was created?  Then post them here.

Comment: @Mchl haha wow. I did not even realize the OP was doing that.... oy...

Comment: Please please please delete all that code, and start again with PDO.

Comment: @BojanSerafimov you do not create new tables for each user. You have a user table which you reference in your other tables...

Comment: @BojanSerafimov How is that faster?

Comment: Mother of all tables...

Comment: "doing queries on smaller databases is faster. why is that an antipattern?"  You are placing a metadata value in as table name  thats a antipattern in SQL. and better normalized tables are easer to query if you need stats about them. your way you need to write much more stats querys for ever user...  SQL ANTI PATTERN..

Comment: It seemed faster because I was searching a smaller table, but I didn't take into account the time it takes to find that table, so it's my mistake.

Comment: @BojanSerafimov you should read this book: [SQL Antipatterns](http://pragprog.com/book/bksqla/sql-antipatterns). One of the chapters there is exactly about what you are trying to do there. It explains why code is bad, what prompts people to write it and provides you with **several** alternatives.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you need to rethink you general pattern.

You should **not** be creating a new table per user!

You should have tables like tests, questions, test_questions, answers, and users.

Something like this:

```
tests:
   id, name, duration
questions:
   id, question
test_questions:
   id, test_id, question_id
users:
   id, name
answers:
   id, test_questions_id, user_id, answer
```

Then you know for which test, which user answered which question easily with one query.

Comment: this does not answer my question, but i'm gonna delete that code anyway.

Comment: @BojanSerafimov how does this not answer your question?

Comment: @BojanSerafimov lolwut ? I recommend you to read [this book](http://www.amazon.com/SQL-Antipatterns-Programming-Pragmatic-Programmers/dp/1934356557).

Comment: My question was why doesn't the table exist.

Comment: @BojanSerafimov Are you on drugs?

Comment: @BojanSerafimov and the answer is -- Do not do that, it is incorrect and antipattern and you will run into issues in the future, here is a better way of doing what you are trying to do.

Comment: @BojanSerafimov You just confirmed that you should go learn the basics before touching any serious code. Otherwise you're commiting a crime against humanity.